# Is there a way to search the entire log entry for text

Tags: json, logging, datadog

Lets suppose I have a log entry like so:

```
{"@timestamp":"2020-11-04T15:44:19.852Z","message":"Done received event", "level":"INFO","eventMetadata.id":"07lbGJhAoql_Em0NF24yT8z","event.partition":"58/64","goober.id":"slba_H1METFVDufIc4CKAhpUqs"}
```

I want to search everything for slba_H1METFVDufIc4CKAhpUqs, not just the message.
I don't want the user to have know any kind of facet name like goober.id.

Any ideas or tips?

Thanks, Eric